# Spring ReflectionUtils#findMethod cannot find java.lang.String#codePointBefore

Tags: java, spring

how to find method `String#codePointBefore`, i tried

```java
ReflectionUtils.findMethod(String.class, "codePointBefore");
ReflectionUtils.findMethod(String.class, "codePointBefore", Integer.class);
```

it's not work.

test environment:

- jdk11
- spring-core 5.3.12

Comment: `int` is not Integer.  You need `int.class` (or Integer.TYPE).

Comment: it's right, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @VGR

```java
ReflectionUtils.findMethod(String.class, "codePointBefore", Integer.TYPE);
ReflectionUtils.findMethod(String.class, "codePointBefore", int.class);
```